# Splitting a Stack in Java

Tags: java, split, stack

I searched the internet and I just couldn't figure out how to split a stack in Java.  I have to split a stack into negatives and positives and then have the negatives at the bottom of the stack.  Just curious!  Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768011/write-a-program-to-sort-a-stack-in-ascending-order

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a method that accepts a Stack
2. Within that method:

   1. Create a Stack for positive values
   2. Create a stack for negative values
   3. for originalStack::size -> loop
   4. stack::pop
   5. if positive, positiveStack::push, else negativeStack::push
   6. end loop
   7. for negativeStack::size -> loop
   8. negativeStack::pop -> originalStack::push
   9. end loop
   10. for positiveStack::size -> loop
   11. positiveStack::pop -> originalStack::push
   12. end loop
3. return originalStack